# Fast way of Converting .doc files to .docx files in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, doc

I have been trying this particular code to convert all the **.doc** files to **.docx** files in a folder.

```
subprocess.call(['soffice', '--headless', '--convert-to', 'docx', filename])
```

But this line of code is taking way too long to execute on a large Data. 
Is there any other method that can do the same thing but fast.

Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing specific to Python there. If it's slow, it's because `soffice` is slow.

Comment: @chepner Okay. Is there any other way to do it then ?

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages.